# Weird setting of latitude labels in cartopy Miller projection

Tags: python, cartopy

Just to make things easy I have reproduced my problem adapting an example from the [gallery of cartopy's latest release](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/gallery/axes_grid_basic.html#sphx-glr-gallery-axes-grid-basic-py)

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 10))

miller = ccrs.Miller(central_longitude=180)

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=miller)

ax.set_global()
ax.coastlines()
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-90, 90.5, 30), crs=miller)
lat_formatter = LatitudeFormatter()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lat_formatter)

plt.show()
```

[image]

For some reason the y axis labels are changed and have weird values.
Potentially something that has to do with LatitudeFormatter ?

Important: For some environment related reasons I'm using cartopy 0.18.0b3.dev15+

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cartopy is giving you exactly what you asked for, which is labels at (-90, -60, -30, 0, 30, 60, 90) **in the Miller projection**, i.e. not in degrees of latitude. Because you are using the `LatitudeFormatter` it is converting these Miller projection points into degrees latitude for you for display.

What it looks like you wanted to do was label in a lat/long coordinate system, so you should use `ccrs.PlateCarree()` as the `crs` argument when creating the ticks, like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.mpl.ticker import LatitudeFormatter
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 10))

miller = ccrs.Miller(central_longitude=180)

ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=miller)

ax.set_global()
ax.coastlines()
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-90, 90.5, 30), crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
lat_formatter = LatitudeFormatter()
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lat_formatter)

plt.show()
```

[image: Miller projection with latitude labels]

Comment: a bit late for asking but.. you write " labels in the Miller projection, i.e. not in degrees of latitude". I'm confused by this statement. How can these two be different ? Shouldn't there be a unique mapping from latitude and longitude (defined on a sphere) to where these values end up being in a projection ? 

I admittedly have small knowledge in this field, so this is surely a beginner's question.